# Time Picker is not placed jquery appended on text box correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I need to get store all event at each and every day those the Event times is captured by dialog div and i getting the start time and end time for each and every events per day but now the problems are

```
    1. Time picker is not placed at the correct text box its automatically changed please some one help me.
    2. I need to show time range i.e given gap for each and every events at half hour please help me friends.
```

MY CODE IN THIS LINK

http://jsbin.com/lixig/3/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
if ((self.offset().top + self.outerHeight(true) + list.outerHeight()) > $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop()) {
    // position the dropdown on top
    list.offset({
        'left': self.offset().left+self.width() ,
        'top': self.offset().top - list.height()+ self.innerHeight()
    });
} else {
    // put it under the input
    list.offset({
        'left':self.offset().left +self.width(),
        'top': self.offset().top
    });
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/cijah/1/edit)

Comment: I think this is `plugin's bug` I tried the `CDN` and got the same `result` see http://jsbin.com/cijah/2/edit

Comment: Its working but not on the `position` which you want. The first one works, as you want. I just created the second to show you, that the `timepicker from github url` is not working for `multiple classes`.